# QGIS grabs incorrect field values for categorized style classification

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

as seen in the first image, the field values QGIS returns when I attempt a 'select by expression' are values found nowhere in the field in question ('FLD_ZONE'). Instead, it returns a selection of values from an entirely different field ('DFIRM_ID').

I notice a similar thing in the properties panel when I ask the style guide to auto-classify a categorized color scheme based on the values of the FLD_ZONE field (second image). It again returns values from the DFIRM_ID field, only this time there are only 3.

Does anyone have a clue as to why these QGIS interfaces are interpreting values of this field incorrectly??

[image: first image]

[image: second image]imgur.com/3A9f0.jpg

Comment: Have you tried exporting the offending layer as a shapefile and adding it back to your TOC to see if the behaviour changes? Is this occurring only with the one layer?

Comment: What type of layer is it? Shape?

Comment: @Geezer Brilliant idea. THat did the trick. FYI, this was a shapefile.